# Parse json from url into mongodb

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to parse, some json data from an url and save it into my mongoDB model. however i can't seem to parse the JSON correctly from the `body`. How can i achieve this?

**Code**

```
router.get('/news', function(req, res){

    request({
        method: "GET",
        url: "URL",
        json: true
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json(body);

        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(info.articles);
    })

});
```

**Snippet of code from the api**

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
    "title": "this is the title",
    "created": "12-09-2015",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "image": "http://url.com/test.jpg",
    "body": "this is the body"
    },
    {
    "title": "this is the title",
    "created": "12-09-2015",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "image": "http://url.com/test.jpg",
    "body": "this is the body"
    }

  ]
}
```

**News model**

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var newsSchema   = new Schema({
    title: String,
    created: String,
    author: String,
    image: String,
    bodyfull: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('news', newsSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what's going on in your example there.

But if you want to retrieve information from a request body in node, you can from a POST request

so

```
var News = require('newsModel'); //wherever it's located

Router.post('/news', function(req,res){
    var infoToParse = req.body;

    var info = JSON.parse(infoToParse);

    var newsItem = new News(info);

    newsItem.save(function(err){
     if(err) return handleError(err)

   });       
 }
```

not sure if that helps at all? I'm no node guru but that's the kind of thing I do

Comment: What i'm trying to do is get data from an api (an url) and then save it into my news model.

Comment: ah you want the node server to pull from a third party api? 
That can be done with Request

[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Comment: i want to pull data from a third party api and insert the objects into my news model

Comment: the json snippet is a example of the thirdparty api